# (not set) values from session_start events appearing for custom dimensions/parameters

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-firebase, gtag.js

We just added GA4 tracking to our website, along with custom parameters on events that were then configured as custom dimensions to be used in reports. After, we noticed "(not set)" values appearing when breaking out by a custom dimension. It appears as 0 Views, but roughly double the Total Sessions.

[image: not set on custom value]

When filtered to "(not set)" for the custom dimension, and looking at the events, it seems these are mostly recorded as "session_start" and "first_visit" events.

[image: events fired on not set dimension values]

Moreover, when filtering out "(not set)" for the custom dimension, the Sessions count for the page_view event does not add up to total, which leads me to think that there are Sessions with no page_view events - though I can't think of how this could happen on our site, and we don't have an app/any app tracking set up.

[image: page view sessions higher than total]

**We compared and we get the same results from the API too.**

Here is the code on our site (following [the gtag guide here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/event-parameters?client_type=gtag)):

```html
                            <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXX"></script>
        <script>
            var ga4ParamsObject = JSON.parse(`{"classification":"Standard","example1":"value1","example2":"value2","example3":"value3"}`);
                        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());

            gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXX', ga4ParamsObject);
        </script>
```

**Questions:**

- Is something incorrect or missing from our implementation that's resulting in (not set) values appearing on custom dimensions?
- Are we not "linking" session_start and first_visit events to page_view events within the session?
- What can explain the Total Sessions being higher than the count of sessions with a page_view event?
- It would appear that multiple parameters within the same session are counted twice when breaking out by these parameters (custom dimensions) - is that expected in GA4 or again something incorrect with our set up?

**Additional notes:**

- We are running analytics.js in parallel
- We've upgraded to 360
- "Collect UA events in GA4" setting is turned off in Admin config
- The GA4 property is connected to GAM, we serve ads on the page, and some advertisers do use gtag.js too, but I checked multiple times and our specific G- measurement ID only appears in the snippet I shared above
- [Here's an example page](https://www.dualshockers.com/netflix-to-establish-cloud-gaming-service/?utm_source=stackoverflow)

---

Thanks to anyone reading this.

Answer (score 6):

Custom parameters are currently not tracked with the `session_start` and `first_visit` automatically collected events which is why your custom parameters are `(not set)` with these two events.

Unfortunately this can impact your reporting depending on the metrics you use. E.g. if you use the `views` metric only and assuming your custom parameter is always set you will not see the `(not set)` value in your report. However if you use the `users` metric you will see the `(not set)` value as `users` will include events such as `session_start` where the custom parameter is not populated.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I year late, but do you happen to have a source please that I can forward to our reporting team who are asking about the missing parameters?